# WPF Неизвестная ошибка сборки, Ссылка не указывает на объект экземпляра

Tags: .net, wpf

Сабж. Такое происходит во всех проектах, независимо от того, какие элементы я разместил в окне. Просто ничего не билдится, вылетает и дело с концом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу полный код

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:gif="clr-namespace:WpfAnimatedGif;assembly=WpfAnimatedGif"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStyle="None"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    AllowsTransparency="false"
    Title="RemotionServer" Height="418.833" Width="338.758">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ConnectButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource NewRetroWaveBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="3"
                                CornerRadius="0, 20, 20, 0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <EventSetter></EventSetter>
    </Style>
    <Brush x:Key="NewRetroWaveBrush">#1E9100</Brush>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
</Grid>
```

При ребилде проблема не уходит

Также если очистить весь MainWindow.xaml от элементов, т.е оставить  и  внутри, то ошибка не уходит всё равно. Т.е появлятся и "с концами"

Посмотрел по логам: 
**error MC1000: Неизвестная ошибка сборки, "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."** 
В интернете ничего дельного по решению данной ошибки нет

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**
Разобрался в причине ошибки

```
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler" />
```

Handler был пуст. Странно, что vs никоим образом не указывала на пропущенный хендлер, а я и не доглядел

Comment: Ну так сделайте Rebuild. 80% за то, что проблема уйдёт.

Comment: Ничего не уходит, ошибка остается. Все ссылки в проекте правильные, ошибок в проекте никаких нет, а предупреждение появляется и проект отказывается запускаться

Comment: Ну окей, закройте студию, удалите у проекта каталоги bin и obj, откройте снова студию, сделайте ещё один Rebuild.

Comment: Ничего всё равно не меняется

Comment: @VladD, обрати внимание, что это не error - а warning

Comment: `<Brush x:Key="NewRetroWaveBrush">#1E9100</Brush>` в начало ресурсов киньте

Comment: и  `BorderBrush="{StaticResource NewRetroWaveBrush}"`

Comment: Он у меня в app.xaml. Если удалить все мои стили из app.xaml, то ничего не меняется тоже. Т.е при полностью пустом проекте у меня вылезает эта ошибка

Comment: @Grundy, после пары ребилдов варнинг "превращается" в ошибку, вообще магия какая то с вижуал студией творится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler" />
```

Handler был пуст. Странно, что vs никоим образом не указывала на пропущенный хендлер, а я и не доглядел